# values of file don't add up

Tags: python, list, file, text

So my question is very specific to my list of code.
I have a list of song names and artists saved in one same file and i have a program to retrieve a random song name and its artist and question the player on the name of the song based on the artist and the first letters of every word in the song.

I have come to a bit of a kerfuffle, however, as my value question[1] meaning the songname does not equal the answer even when the answer is the same.

Here is my list of songs:

```
Macklemore
Can't Hold Us
Avicii
The Nights
bbnos
Nursery
Bees Gees
Stayin' Alive
The Animals
The House Of The Rising Sun
Bugzy Malone
Memory Lane
The Score
Stronger
Imagine Dragons
Warriors
Lincoln Park
Numb
Queen
Bohemian Rhapsody
```

This includes the artist followed by the song name.

My problem is that when i type in the song name when asked, it never accepts it as the name of the song, HOWEVER in the case of Bohemian Rhapsody, the program recognises the name. This is the only song it recognises and i don't know why. Please help.

Any responses greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#PREPARATION OF DATA SET

import time,random
gameend = False
score = 0
data = open('MusicQuiz data.txt','r') #opening data set
try:
    cont = data.readlines()
finally:
    data.close() #reading the data under  cont  variable

num = 0
while num < 20:        #combining and sorting the data set into pairs of the author and song title
    cont[num] += cont[(num+1)]
    num += 2
odds = 1
while odds < 11: #Defying all odds (removing excess odds of pairs)
    cont.remove(cont[odds])
    odds += 1


#SETTING UP AUTHENTICATION


username = str(input("What is your name?\n~ ")) #asking for authentication

if username == 'adminpassword':
    print('\n'.join(cont)) #admin check to see the current data set

file = open('MusicQuiz authentication.txt','r')
try:
    contents = file.read() #opening and reading the vaild users file
finally:
    file.close()
if (contents.count(username) >= 1): #checking if the input value is in the data set
    print("\nPassword valid")
else:
    print("\nPassword not valid")
    delay = input("\nQuit?..") #if the username is not in the data set, it quits
    quit()
print("\nWelcome, " +username +".")
t = 1
time.sleep(t)
print("\nQUESTION 1:\n")


#RANDOM SONG & ARTIST SELECTION


while gameend == False:
    random.shuffle(cont)
    Q = cont[0]
    qfile = open('MusicQuiz temp.txt','w')
    try:
        qfile.write(Q)
    finally:
        qfile.close()

    question = []
    songname = []
    contfile = open('MusicQuiz temp.txt', 'r')
    try:
        contents = contfile.readlines()
    finally:
        contfile.close()
    for line in contents:
        question.append(line)
    for c in question[1]:
        if c == c.upper():
            songname.append(c)
        elif c == c.lower():
            songname.append('.')
        elif c == ' ':
            songname.append(' ')
    print(question[0])
    print(''.join(songname))
    response = input("\n\n")
    if response == question[1]:
        score += 3
        print("correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong. Second attempt:")
        response2 = input("")
        if response2 == question[1]:
            score += 1
            print("correct")
        else:
            print("WRONG!")
            print("Your score was " +str(score))
            gameend = True
quit()
```

Comment: When you run this using a debugger, what is the *first* point at which it behaves differently than you expected?

Comment: @Scott Hunter  I don't know how to use a debugger yet. I'm about a week into coding.

Comment: Some random comments: Use context managers to handle files objects. Much cleaner than try-finally, and possibly safer. While loops that are similar to `odds = 1; while odds < 11: do a thing; odds += 1` should just be for loops with ranges instead. `input()` returns a string, so `str(input())` is redundant. `... == True` is doubly wrong/incorrect, just use `if ... :`, for example. `c == c.upper()` --> `c.isupper()`. I can't tell where `quit()` is defined.

Comment: _I don't know how to use a debugger yet. I'm about a week into coding._ I think you would benefit from learning a bit more first, then. Stack Overflow is not meant to replace guides or tutorials.

Comment: yeah dw before this ive completed all of sololearn and a lot of youtube tutorials. I only started like a week ago afterall and im mostly doing pygame right now. Just no tutorials or guides tend to mention debuggers i have found. It was just one bug i couldn't wrap my head around. I've tidied up the code and sorted the problem now along with making it so the code allows any amount of songs and it doesnt repeat them. I'm doing highscores right now though and from an experienced programmer's point of view, @AMC what do you think is the best way to sort highscores?(both name and scores stored) thx

Comment: Can you share all the data we need to run this? See: [mcve].